# How to enable CORS on nodejs express redirect?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, cors

I am using nodejs express as my API in the backend. I wonder how to enable CORS on `redirect` method.

Below is my express redirect code:

```
res.redirect(redirectUrl);
```

when client sends request to above API it will redirect the request to a `s3` but I get below error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s3-ap-southeast-
2.amazonaws.com/index.html' (redirected from 
'http://localhost:9090/v0/api') from origin 'http://localhost:9090' has 
been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass 
access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
 the requested resource.
```

the frontend is running under `http://localhost:9090` and the frontend domain has been added on CORS in the s3 bucket. It works fine if I send the request to `https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/index.html` directly from the browser. So I think the problem is on `nodejs express redirect` method. How can I enable CORS for the redirect?

I know how to enable `CORS` but my problem relates to `redirect`. How can I make the redirect work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors)

Comment: It is different because my issue is about redirect not direct connect

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with your backend or frontend, you'll have to add CORS policy in your S3 bucket

Please follow below steps to enable CORS on your S3 bucket

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon S3 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/.
2. In the Bucket name list, choose the name of the bucket that you want to create a bucket policy for.
3. Choose Permissions, and then choose CORS configuration.
4. In the CORS configuration editor text box, type or copy and paste a new CORS configuration, or edit an existing configurationto make it look as below.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
> <CORSRule>
>     <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
>     <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
> </CORSRule>
> </CORSConfiguration>
> ```

5. Choose Save.

This should work for you.

Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html

Comment: will this work with ```res.redirect```?  from what I understood and know cors doesn't work with ```redirect``` but will work with normal request.

Comment: The best option here is to return the url and redirect from the front-end.

Comment: Tested & working well with res.redirect as well. CORS policy has to be done on the destination & not the source

Comment: I don't know how you got it to work but ```res.redirect(url)``` doesn't work for me. see my question here with examples https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758422/getting-cors-error-when-redirecting-with-express-server

Comment: You have to enable cors on the destination url where you are redirecting user, you are redirecting to google.com which does not have cors enabled